# how to block email address from the same mail domain in postfix?

Tags: postfix

Is there any way to block the mail address in the same domain in postfix?
I know this can be done with different domains but I didn't find any helpful link in Google.

I want that some of the users in our domain will not be able to send emails to the users of the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [policy server](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) to accomplish that.